# Determine for what values $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^2}$ is convergent.

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I am not sure where to start on this one. I know that $z^n$ can be written as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-z}$. But I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: Do you know what is the radius of convergence? Also, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$ converges.

Comment: do the  convergence tests from real analysis, translate to complex analysis?

Comment: More or less, but if you don't know what I asked it be will quite difficult.

Comment: Yes i understand what the radius of convergence is, but its been a while since ive used it.

Answer (score 0):

For the radius of convergence:

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac 1n}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt[n]{n^2}}=1\implies R=1$$

So the series converges absolutely for $\;|z|<1\;$ . You can now check directly that it converges also on the unit circle $\;|z|=1\:$ , and the comment by Geoff can be helpful